# Windows Phone 8.1 (XAML). Strange text cutting bug inside ListView (with some conditions)

Tags: xaml, listview, pivot, windows-phone-8.1, textblock

The following XAML page markup

```
<Page
    x:Class="XXXX.TestPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <Pivot Title="Title0">
            <PivotItem Header="Header0">
                <ListView SelectionMode="Multiple">
                    <ListViewItem>
                        <TextBlock 
                            Text="0123456 0123456 0123456 01234 0123456" 
                            TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"
                            FontSize="24"/>
                    </ListViewItem>
                </ListView>
            </PivotItem>
        </Pivot>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

causes the strange text cutting bug (two digits are cut off, red arrow is mine):
[image: text cutting bug]

Tested under Windows Phone 8.1 Emulator (WVGA, 512MB, 4 inch, 480x800).

Required conditions: `ListView with SelectionMode="Multiple"` and `Pivot` control. This means that if I change SelectionMode to other value, or remove ListView and place TextBox right inside PivotItem, or remove Pivot and place ListView right inside Grid - the bug disappears.

Can anyone explain the reason of the bug and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior.

Consider, instead, the following XAML:

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar>
        <AppBarToggleButton Icon="Favorite" Checked="AppBarToggleButton_Checked" Unchecked="AppBarToggleButton_Unchecked" />
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>

<Grid>
    <Pivot Title="Title0">
        <PivotItem Header="Header0">
            <ListView x:Name="MyListView" Background="Blue">
                <ListViewItem>
                    <TextBlock 
                        Text="0123456 0123456 0123456 01234 0123456" 
                        TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"
                        FontSize="24" />
                </ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>
                    <TextBlock 
                        Text="0123456 0123456 0123456 01234 0123456" 
                        TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"
                        FontSize="24" />
                </ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>
                    <TextBlock 
                        Text="0123456 0123456 0123456 01234 0123456" 
                        TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"
                        FontSize="24" />
                </ListViewItem>
            </ListView>
        </PivotItem>
    </Pivot>
</Grid>
```

with corresponding code-behind:

```cs
private void AppBarToggleButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyListView.SelectionMode = ListViewSelectionMode.Multiple;
}

private void AppBarToggleButton_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyListView.SelectionMode = ListViewSelectionMode.None;
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Toggling the selection checkboxes doesn't cause the list box content widths to be recalculated.

Comment: Well, I don't agree that it's "expected" (at least it's not expected by me) but yes, now I see that this is how ListView actually works. I see in default ListViewItem control template that when multiselect is activated then checkbox and content container are moved by 40.5 pixels to the right. And actually checkbox is always there, it's just placed outside of the control by default. For me it looks like stupid layout solution, but I'm not XAML expert. Anyway, now I can fix this by specifying appropriate margin for my content directly or through the control template. Thanks.